# How to call a type List method in another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to use the getFreeAdjacentLocation method from the Field class but I am getting an error from the CleverSheep class stating it 'cannot find the symbol - method getFreeAdjacentLocation(Location)'

I have a class Field

```
public class Field
{
 // some fields
 // constructor
 // other methods
 public List<Location> getFreeAdjacentLocations(Location location)
 {
    validLocation(location);
    List<Location> free = new LinkedList<Location>();
    List<Location> adjacent = adjacentLocations(location);
    for(Location next : adjacent) {
        if(getObjectAt(next) == null) {
            free.add(next);
        }
    }
    return free;
  }
```

I have a clever sheep class

```
public class CleverSheep
{
   // constructor
   public CleverSheep(Field field, Location location, int n)
   {
      super(field, location);
   }

 public void act()
 {
    if (isAlive()) {
        Location newLocation =       getField().freeAdjacentLocation(getLocation());
        Location freeLocation = getField().getFreeAdjacentLocation(getLocation());
        if(newLocation != null) {
            moveToLocation(newLocation);
        }

        // If Wolf is in this location
        else if (newLocation == null ) {
            moveToLocation(freeLocation);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: where is getField()?

Comment: It's `getFreeAdjacentLocations` not `getFreeAdjacentLocation`. See the _s_?

Comment: @LawrenceAiello getField() is from another class Animal (abstract class)

Comment: @GriffeyDog *cries* thanks lol, that cleared the error but now I am getting another error. This time it says 'incompatible types: java.util.List<Location> cannot be converted to Location'.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is called `getFreeAdjacentLocations()` but in the second block you are calling `getFreeAdjacentLocation()` without the "s".

You may also need to recheck your variable types, since the return type of `getFreeAdjacentLocations()` is `List<Location>` and the type of `freeLocation` is `Location`. You would need something like this:

```
List<Location> freeLocations = getField().getFreeAdjacentLocations(getLocation());
```

The method `moveToLocation()` may complain since it probably expects a single `Location` and not a list. So you will need to process the `freeLocations` list and choose one location to pass to it. For example:

```
for (Location freeLocation : freeLocations) {
    if (satisfiesCondition(freeLocation)) {
        moveToLocation(freeLocation);
        break;
    }
}
```

Where `satisfiesCondition()` is a method you would need to implement and that would return `true` if `freeLocation` is the location you want to move to.

Comment: I changed the 'freeLocation' to 'List<Location>'. I am not getting another error 'incompatible types: java.util.List<Location> cannot be converted to Location'.

Comment: It looks like you're doing the same thing with newLocation. Check the line where the exception was thrown and see if that is the case.

Comment: the exception was thrown at 'moveToLocation(freeLocation)' within the else if statement. The freeAdjacentLocation looks is stated as 'public Location freeAdjacentLocation(Location location){...}'.

Comment: The problem is that moveToLocation expects a single location and not a list. You need to choose one location from the list as argument to the method. I updated the answer.